# Accessing managed arrays and pinning

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I am currently writing a set of Wrappers for some native C++ code. In the wrapper I take a managed array as input and intend to use the content of the array to call a native c++ constructor. For some reason i seem to need to either pin the array or extract the values separately from the constructor call. Here are some examples of what i mean.

The constructor for the native type has type signature like this:

```
NativeType(const double &d)
```

Initial attempt:

```
public ref class ExampleWrapper
{
     ExampleWrapper(array<double> ^ in)
     {
        for(int i= 0; i< in->Length; ++i)
        {
            NativeType test(in[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

This comes back with an error and will not compile. Next I tried this

```
public ref class ExampleWrapper
{
     ExampleWrapper(array<double> ^ in)
     {
        for(int i= 0; i< in->Length; ++i)
        {
            double d = in[i];
            NativeType test(d);
        }
     }
}
```

which seems to work fine. Lastly i tried pinning the array like this:

```
public ref class ExampleWrapper
{
     ExampleWrapper(array<double> ^ in)
     {
        pin_ptr<double> pin_in = &in[0];
        for(int i= 0; i< in->Length; ++i)
        {
            NativeType test(pin_in[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Which also seems to work fine.

What i would like to know is why the first example does not work, while the other two seem to work fine. Additionally I would like to know what is the preferred method to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the first example fail?

It fails because you're asking the compiler to take the address of a managed variable (a single double inside the double array) and pass it to unmanaged code, but that is illegal.

> Why does the second example pass?

Because the `d` is not in managed memory, it's a local variable in the wrapper code. You can initialize it from the managed memory array since you're only taking the value (the double), not the address.

> Why does the third example pass?

Because you're pinning the array to a fixed memory location, and now it can be safely passed into the unmanaged code.
(P.S., I think you meant `pin_ptr<double> pin_in = &in[0];`)

Comment: So, is the issue that the constructor takes a reference? I have noticed that i further down have similar example where the constructor has the type signature NativeType(int i) which seems to compile just fine, with the equivalent of the first example.

Comment: Yes, that would work just fine, since you'll be passing a primitive value, not an object / memory address.

Answer (score 2):

The `in` array is a managed object, it does not have a stable address.  At any possible moment in time the garbage collector can kick in and move the object while it compacts the heap.  It is not terribly likely that this will happen, after all you are calling native code so the GC has no reason to trigger a collection.  It is however not zero, other threads in the program may be allocating at the same time.

When this happens then disaster strikes.  It is a *const double* so at least the native code cannot corrupt the GC heap.  The actual double value it reads is however random.

The C++/CLI compiler can detect this possible mishap and complains.  You have to provide a stable address for the double&.  Copying it into a local variable is certainly the easiest way, it is stored on the stack and those variables are never moved.  Using pin_ptr<> is a fine workaround as well, it is a *very* cheap way to pin a managed object.  It only sets a bit in the table that the jitter generates that helps the GC discover references stored in local variables and CPU registers.  It only costs anything when an actual collection occurs, the CLR discovers it when performing a stack walk to find references.

---

Passing a double& is rather odd, very important that you take a look at the native code.  With the expectation that you'll find that it stores the reference instead of storing the value.  That's a Very Big Problem, the workarounds you found are only good enough for the life of the constructor call.  The native code is going to read garbage when it uses the reference later.

You then **must** create a stable reference that stays valid beyond the constructor call, use the native *new* operator in your wrapper and store it in a field.  Clean it up in your finalizer, again after checking that the native code can no longer dereference it.  That normally only comes to a good end when your finalizer also destroys the native class object.

Comment: The actual type in the constructor is a templated type type. It simply happens to resolve to double in this case.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer in any way.